# Promise.all().then() resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Using Node 4.x. When you have a `Promise.all(promises).then()` what is the proper way to resolve the data and pass it to the next `.then()`?

I want to do something like this:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(function(data){
  // Do something with the data here
}).then(function(data){
  // Do more stuff here
});
```

But I'm not sure how to get the data to the 2nd `.then()`. I can't use `resolve(...)` in the first `.then()`. I figured out I can do this:

```
return Promise.all(promises).then(function(data){
  // Do something with the data here
  return data;
}).then(function(data){
  // Do more stuff here
});
```

But that doesn't seem like the proper way to do it... What is the right approach to this?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

> But that doesn't seem like the proper way to do it..

That is indeed the proper way to do it (or at least *a* proper way to do it). This is a key aspect of promises, they're a pipeline, and the data can be massaged by the various handlers in the pipeline.

Example:

```js
const promises = [
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0, 1)),
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0, 2))
];
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(data => {
    console.log("First handler", data);
    return data.map(entry => entry * 10);
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log("Second handler", data);
  });
```

*(`catch` handler omitted for brevity. In production code, **always** either propagate the promise, or handle rejection.)*

The output we see from that is:

```
First handler [1,2]
Second handler [10,20]
```

...because the first handler gets the resolution of the two promises (`1` and `2`) as an array, and then creates a new array with each of those multiplied by 10 and returns it. The second handler gets what the first handler returned.

If the additional work you're doing is synchronous, you can also put it *in* the first handler:

Example:

```js
const promises = [
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0, 1)),
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0, 2))
];
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(data => {
    console.log("Initial data", data);
    data = data.map(entry => entry * 10);
    console.log("Updated data", data);
    return data;
  });
```

...but if it's asynchronous you won't want to do that as it ends up getting nested, and the nesting can quickly get out of hand.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. So is it not possible to `reject` a value after the initial `Promise` function? Or will throwing an error anywhere in the chain take you to the `.catch()`? If that is the case, what is the point of `reject` in the first place? Why not just throw error? Thanks again,

Comment: @JakeWilson: Those are different questions. But you're confusing two separate things: *Creating* and settling the promise, and *handling* the promise. When you're creating and settling the promise, you use `resolve` and `reject`. When you're *handling*, if your processing fails, you do indeed throw an exception to trigger the failure path. And yes, you can also throw an exception from the original `Promise` callback (rather than using `reject`), but not all failures are exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

Today NodeJS supports new `async/await` syntax. This is an easy syntax and makes the life much easier

```
async function process(promises) { // must be an async function
    let x = await Promise.all(promises);  // now x will be an array
    x = x.map( tmp => tmp * 10);              // proccessing the data.
}

const promises = [
   new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0, 1)),
   new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0, 2))
];

process(promises)
```

Learn more:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: how can i pass parameters to each individual promise from process? @ Aminadav Glickshtein

Answer (score 4):

Your `return data` approach is correct, that's an example of [promise chaining](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/then#chaining). If you return a promise from your `.then()` callback, JavaScript will resolve that promise and pass the data to the next `then()` callback.

Just be careful and make sure you handle errors with `.catch()`. [`Promise.all()` rejects as soon as one of the promises in the array rejects](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/promise-all).