# Returning empty arrow function on promise chain

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, arrow-functions

I am trying to understand a block of code here, which I believe is redundant code, which could be deleted but maybe I am wrong, here is the code:

```
return(
    myModule.getSomething(args.url)
    .then(stream => module.uploadData({
      param1: args.param1,
      param2: args.param2,
      param3: stream,
    }))
    .then(() => myBroker.dispatch({
        queueUrl: myQueueUrl,
        payload: JSON.stringify(args.payload),
      })
    )
    .then(msgInfo => {}) .  //This line can be removed right?
    .catch(error => {
      myBroker.dispatch({
        queueUrl: anotherQueueUrl,
        payload: JSON.stringify({ type: 'error', payload: `[ERROR] ${error}` }),
      });

      throw error;
    })
  );
```

I believe the line:

.then(msgInfo => {})

can be deleted right? the arrow function does nothing, the msgInfo is something that the previous then clause returns after calling myBroker.dispatch, and because of that, I could remove the line I mentioned right?

Can someone give me a clear explanation on this?
Why that line exists? Or explain why can't I delete it?

PS: the function getSomething and uploadData returns a promise, the dispatch function I am not so sure because it looks like this:

```
return(
    client.sendMessage(parameters).promise()
    .then(data => data)
  );
```

It returns only a object which is 'data' right? or does it return a promise as well, because it contains the then clause in the end?

This syntax notation using multiple 'then' and arrow functions confuses me,

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It is not clear why the line exists. Yes, the line can be removed.

Comment: The function doesn't do nothing, it returns an empty object, which eventually your top level return statement will use as its return value. Clarification, your top level return returns a promise which will resolve to { } when all is said and done.

Comment: You can use promise.all for handling multiple api calls like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33073509/promise-all-then-resolve)

Comment: "The function doesn't do nothing, it returns an empty object," @JSager. Nope. It returns undefined. Curly brackets create a block here, not  object literal. So this function "swallows" `msgInfo` and makes the promise to be resolved to `undefined` instead.

Comment: I thought if you had a single arg lambda with no parentheses and a block scope declared you get an invalid syntax error.

Comment: Huh. You're right. ESLint would explode on me if I tried that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can think of for why that line would exist would be if the function this whole block is being used in is somewhere such that the resolve value of `myBroker.dispatch` should not be (or is better not) exposed to the consumer of the larger function. For example:

```
const thisModule = (() => {
  const myBroker = ...;
  function getSomethingAndDispatchBroker() {
    return(
      myModule.getSomething(args.url)
      .then(stream => module.uploadData({
        param1: args.param1,
        param2: args.param2,
        param3: stream,
      }))
      .then(() => myBroker.dispatch({
        queueUrl: myQueueUrl,
        payload: JSON.stringify(args.payload),
      }))
      .then(msgInfo => {})
      .catch(error => {
        myBroker.dispatch({
          queueUrl: anotherQueueUrl,
          payload: JSON.stringify({ type: 'error', payload: `[ERROR] ${error}` }),
        });
        throw error;
      })
    );
  }
  return { getSomethingAndDispatchBroker };
})();
```

Here, the function `getSomethingAndDispatchBroker` can be called from outside, but perhaps the resolve value of `myBroker.dispatch` is better kept internal to the `thisModule` - either due to privacy, or due to code clarity - perhaps you only want users of the function to know *if the Promise resolved* (if the process succeeded), without telling them unnecessary details.

Still, if none of that is a concern, then yes, feel free to remove the `.then(msgInfo => {})` line.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I noticed that the line can actually be removed, there is no need to have it on my case.